# google street view with custom panorama and markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I have this code that uses a custom Google street view panorama and creates some custom markers.

```js
function initialize() {

    var panoOptions = {
        pano: 'a9V_yZU01A7nTQW7S4Hxjw',
        pov: {
            heading: 0,
            pitch:0
        },
        zoom: 0
    };
    var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('virtualTour'), panoOptions);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var markers = [];
    var locations = [
        ['<div style="width: 170px;">MARKERS 1</div>', 37.869197, -122.254583]
    ];

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
            map: pano,
            visible: false,
            zIndex: 999
        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(pano, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        markers.push(marker); // save all markers
    }



    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(true);
        markers[i].setMap(pano);
    }

    pano.setVisible(true);

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My question is: why are markers shown only after I move through google street view arrows on floor?

I want markers to be shown on initialize function. Can anyone help me? I have created a jsfiddle for my project:
http://jsfiddle.net/7HpmE/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

I was able to fix your problem by simply reloading the pano after the markers have been added.
All I did was replacing the following line:

```
pano.setVisible(true);
```

(the panorama is visible by default) with:

```
pano.setPano('a9V_yZU01A7nTQW7S4Hxjw');
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfidle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7mfswdbg/